# AJAX Instant messenger

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, instantmessenger

Hi I am trying to make an AJAX instant messenger. I currently have a website (with user logon, admin area etc.) using PHP, MySql, Java Script etc and an AJAX chat prog with 2 chat rooms (and users in room list etc) and it works really good, but dont really know where to go from here (instant messenger wise). I have done some researh which has suggested using an AJAX listener for new messages but I cant find much information on it...or if indeed this is needed or i should use something else. If anyone has any advice where I should go next it would be very, very much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For a chat or chat-like application which needs realtime and immediate responses probably [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is a way to go. The mentioned [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is also built on node.js. It can be used both on server and client side.

There are lot of blogs/tutorials about node.js. Or you may like [this](http://peepcode.com/products/nodejs-i), even if it is for a little fee.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at www.socket.io for the real-time stuff.

There's even an instant messenger example on the site IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go with something like [AJAX Chat](https://blueimp.net/ajax/), it's free and open source!

I think it might get you going!

Answer (score 0):

Use Stream Hub. Reverse AJAX - pretty cool stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can try cometd of Dojo Foundation!
http://cometd.org/

Answer (score 0):

### Node.js

Like a lot of people mentioned I would use node.js/socket.io for this instead of PHP. It has been created to tackle such sort of problems.

### Redis

But if you really want to create somethink like this in PHP I would do it using [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/)(needs to be installed). It has blocking list operations which really help you create something like this. When some user sents a message to another user we [push](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/RpushCommand) the message to corresponding blocking list of that user. The user listens to an unique [blocking list](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/BlpopCommand)(key) to receive messages.

### Can not install Redis

Then you have to use MySQL insert into a table and poll table frequently, but not to much to kill your server/database.